# Any inkling why my Docker Node image update continuously crashes, saying its unable to find /bin/node in the container

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules, nodemon

My node application was giving me some trouble when I was adding some Bookshelfjs Model hooks and after some time I deduced that I could/should update the node version

I updated from 14.8 to 15 in all of my Dockerfile(s) but my primary application just refuses to start, saying:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
/app/app-name/node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: 1: /app/app-name/node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: This: not found
```

I did try removing `nodemon` and spinning up the app container with `node` however that yielded the same results. I also made sure to update the package versions that I am using, as I suspected `cross-env` or `nodemon` didn't work with the newer version of node (this did not work either). It seems like I need to create/update a symlink to where node lives, but I'm not sure how to approach that with a Docker container that isn't starting.

Any clues to send me in the right direction here?

Comment: Are you starting the container with a volume for your `node_modules` directory?  The content of this volume will never get updated, and is probably pointing at the old version of Node.  Deleting volume mounts that overwrite the code in the image might help the issue.

Comment: Yes, so I was creating an anonymous volume for node_modules (`- /app/app-name/node_modules`) so that the local folder wasn't copied over. I tried commenting this out and doing a rebuild (`docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate`) but maybe I didn't do everything in the right order (e.g. `docker-compose down -v` or purging existing data in Docker/Desktop before rebuilding. I've since done those things, done a rebuild and it appears to not have fixed the issue :/

Comment: It seems I goofed somewhere along the way... When updating my local node.js version (using NVM), I somehow actually installed `node` as a package dependency in the application mentioned. Removing this and rebuilding (without the anonymous volume included in docker-compose.yml) has fixed my app. I'll leave the volume out as that seems to prevent other, similar issues from occurring. Thanks @david-maze